# Passing request parameter into middleware which uses 'createHandler' function of 'graphql-http'

Tags: javascript, express, graphql, middleware, req

I have created an express server which uses GraphQL for handling requests over HTTP. Among others, the express server has the two middlewares below.

```
app.use(authenticate);

app.use('/graphql', createHandler({ schema }));
```

The authenticate middleware invokes a function which has `req, res and next` as parameters and in certain conditions assigns a value to `req.user`.

How can I pass the `req` object into the next middleware which is responsible for handling GraphQL requests?

I've searched for it in graphql-http's documentation but no luck. Any help will be appreciated.
Link to the package's documentation: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-http#with-express

Comment: Please share enough code. Otherwise we have to guess what exactly you are doing here

Comment: I'll try to be more explanatory. In the `authenticate` middleware I'm checking if the incoming request contains a `session` parameter in it's headers. If it does, I search in the db for that user and if I find him, I set req.user = userFound and call next(). What I want to do, is pass the request object in the next middleware in the chain, which is the one handling GraphQL requests. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently a way to achieve what I wanted is the below code

```
app.use(
  '/graphql',
  createHandler({
    schema,
    context: (req) => ({
      user: req.raw.user,
      random: req.raw.random
    }),
  })
);
```

If you need to pass the whole `req` object, then you can adjust the `context` field of the `createHandler` function like shown below. However, in the resolver you'll have to access fields of the `req` object like this: `user = req.req.raw.user`

```
    context: (req) => ({
      req
    }),
```

Comment: What I would add is that for those migrating from express-graphql to graphql-http like me, in addition to amending my middleware to match the above, thanks to Kristian, I had to change: "context.body.variables" to "context.res.variables"